# Monthly based email alert

Tags: email-alert

I would like send an email alert on a specific day of every month (say 15th of every month). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can create a scheduler class (to run a batch class on 15th day of every month), batch class (this class will have logic to send email to as per logic). You can check following thread for your requirement, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-send-weekly-email-to-email-fields-of-records

Answer (score 0):

You can use time based workflow. For triggering workflow create a checkbox 'send mail' or as per your choice. Use this checkbox as entry criteria. Hope this will help you.

Cheers!!!

Comment: my email is not dependent on any object so I guess I need not go for workflows

Comment: Then go for batch class and scheduler for scheduling the batch class.